# Pycsw Harvest SOS Error Exception

Tags: python, sqlite, csw, pycsw

when I　used the Harvest operation by the pycsw, and there was a Exception as the following picture：[image]

Picture 1: The Response of Harvest Operation

[image]

Picture 2: The document default.cfg setting
so how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question to replace the pictures of errors and code with their text to aid future searches, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following as per http://docs.pycsw.org/en/latest/transactions.html for SQLite3 CSW-T requirements:

- ensure the database file indeed exists in `/var/www/pycsw/tests/suites/cite/data/records.db`
- ensure the database file **and** the parent directory is writeable